# Incorporating a Manipulation in an Animation

Tags: differential-equations

I am having trouble incorporating a manipulation into my animation. I want to be able to maniuplate the 5 constants at the beginning.

Am I going to need to combine all of the code into one string?

```
 N0 = 10; ρ = .1; d = 1; ϵ = 2; j = 1
eqone = Flatten[
           Join[
           Table[x[i]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[i][t]^2)*x[i]'[t] - x[i][t] + d (z[t] - x[i][t]), 
                {i, 0, N0}], 
           {z'[t] == ρ*d/N0 (Sum[x[i][t] - z[t], {i, 0, N0}]) - j*z[t], z[0] == 1,
           x[0][0]        == 0, 
           x[0]'[0]       == 0, 
           x[N0/2][0]     == 0, 
           x[N0/2]'[0]    == 0}, 
           Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
           Table[x[i][0]  == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
           Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}], 
           Table[x[i][0]  == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}]]];

eqtwo = NDSolve[eqone, Append[Table[x[i], {i, 0, N0}], z], {t, 500}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Animate[ptss = Table[{i, x[i][t]} /. eqtwo, {i, 0, N0}]; 
  ListPlot[ptss, PlotRange -> {{0, N0}, {-5, 5}}, 
                 PlotStyle -> Directive@AbsolutePointSize@4, 
                 Epilog -> {Line@ptss[[All, 1]]}, ImageSize -> Large], 
        {t, 0, 500}, 
        AnimationRate -> 2, 
        AnimationRepetitions -> 2, 
        AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the support for animation that'a built into Manipulate? Why can't you replace your Animate with a Manipulate?

Comment: Don't delete your questions as soon as you get an answer. You're just wasting people's time for your personal gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is this: Replace `animate` by `Manipulate`. Add a control for time. The slider in Mathematica automatically has build into it play/pause/stop/advance options build into it. Click on the little `+` to open it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you do not need Animate. You move all your code under Manipulate. This is standard use of Manipulate, which has the form `Manipulate[expression, controlVariables, initilizationCode]`

Here is your question answered using `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{eqone, eqtwo, x, z, ptss, t, i},

  eqone = Flatten[Join[
     Table[
      x[i]''[t] == \[Epsilon]*(1 - x[i][t]^2)*x[i]'[t] - x[i][t] + 
        d (z[t] - x[i][t]), {i, 0, no}],

     {z'[t] == \[Rho]*d/no (Sum[x[i][t] - z[t], {i, 0, no}]) - j*z[t],
      z[0] == 1,
      x[0][0] == 0,
      x[0]'[0] == 0,
      x[no/2][0] == 0,
      x[no/2]'[0] == 0
      },

     Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, no/2 - 1}],
     Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, no/2 - 1}],
     Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, no/2 + 1, no}],
     Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, no/2 + 1, no}]
     ]
    ];

  eqtwo = 
   NDSolve[eqone, Append[Table[x[i], {i, 0, no}], z], {t, tmax}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];

  ptss = Table[{i, x[i][t]} /. eqtwo, {i, 0, no}];
  ListPlot[ptss /. t -> tmax, PlotRange -> {{0, no}, {-5, 5}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@AbsolutePointSize@4, 
   Epilog -> {Line@ptss[[All, 1]] /. t -> tmax}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Frame -> True]
  ],

 {{no, 6, "NO"}, 2, 20, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{\[Rho], .1, "\[Rho]"}, .1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{d, 1, "d"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{\[Epsilon], 2, "\[Epsilon]"}, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize-> Tiny},
 {{j, 2, "j"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{tmax, 1, "t"}, 1, 500, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 Alignment -> Center,  FrameMargins -> 1, SynchronousInitialization -> True,
 ContinuousAction -> True, Alignment -> Center, Paneled -> True,
 Frame -> False, AutorunSequencing -> Automatic, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]